# How to draw NSPopupButtonCell highlighted image

Tags: macos, nspopupbutton, nstoolbar, nscell, nspopupbuttoncell

I have NSPopupButton inside `NSToolbar` that has `borderder = false` which is having some color burn blend when highlighted. If I use `bordered = true` the image is drawn with nice dark overlay.

I am trying to achieve to draw highlighted state the same way as it is in `bordered=true`

PS: NSButtonCell with `bordered = false` works out of the box.

I can achieve the behaviour by having `bordered = true` and overriding `drawBezel` and do nothing there but I want to know

Things I tried:

- highlightsBy
- interiorBackgroundStyle
- setCellAttribute

-

```
class ToolbarPopUpButtonCell : NSPopUpButtonCell {

  override var isHighlighted: Bool {
      get { return true }
      set { super.isHighlighted = newValue }
  }   

  override func drawImage(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
      super.drawImage(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
  }


  //used in case bordered = true so we do nothing
  override func drawBezel(withFrame frame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {

  }

  //doesn't work
  override var interiorBackgroundStyle: NSView.BackgroundStyle
      {
      return .raised
  }
}

  class ToolbarPopUpButton: NSPopUpButton {

  override func awakeFromNib() {
      cell?.setCellAttribute(.cellLightsByBackground, to: 1)
  }

  override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
      return NSMakeSize(32 + 5, 32)
  }
}
```

Notice the image on right which works for `bordered = false` (`NSButtonCell`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only hack I found is to draw a subsitute cell. Still seeking a better solution.

```
- (void)drawImageWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSImage *image = [self image];
    NSButtonCell *swapCell = [[NSButtonCell alloc] initImageCell:image];
    [swapCell setHighlighted:[self isHighlighted]];
    [swapCell drawImage:image withFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
```